# Use a custom docker image for auto-clustering with Jelastic cloud scripting (JPS)

Tags: jelastic

I am trying to deploy a container with a custom docker image and auto-clustering using cloud scripting, but it does not work.

I tried with the official [Postgres Primary-Secondary Cluster JPS](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/postgres/tree/v2.0.0) by removing "nodeType" and adding the "image" directive to specify a custom one, but this gives me the following error:

> Clusterization for the docker node group with the current template tag is not supported. Contact support for assistance.

And when I specify for instance a specific "nodeGroup":

> Clusterization for the sqldb node group with the current template tag is not supported

Same result for all images, even for the official postgres one.

Is it possible to set up auto-clustering using a custom docker image? If yes, how? Should I rewrite auto-clustering.yml and use a custom "baseUrl" to point to it?

I read the entire Jelastic Cloud Scripting documentation on [docs.cloudscripting.com](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/) and tried all possible variations with different applications from the JPS collection that come with auto-clustering, same result.